# Bug with my object un-snapping objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have basic snapping of objects in place in my test scene, but when I go to unsnap the objects the snapped object will resnap unless I move it away very quickly.
For context of the scene setup, I want to implement snapping objects in VR so I have a smaller parent object inside the object I'm moving to represent the hand the object would be parented to in VR. Also I have the snapping script (first one below) attached to the 'hand' object, and am using trigger colliders on the hand & the square obj it attaches to.

Any clue how I can fix this so I don't need to pull quickly to decouple the object?

[Video of the bug happening](https://youtu.be/MQK78MqaXs0)

Below are the scripts I'm using to implement this

```
    public class snap : MonoBehaviour, collider_helper.collider_help_reciever
{
    public Transform snapObj;
    public Transform SnapTarget;
    bool snapped = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("enter");
        if (snapped == false && other.transform.GetInstanceID() == SnapTarget.GetInstanceID())
        {
            snapObj.position = SnapTarget.position;
            snapObj.rotation = SnapTarget.rotation;
            snapObj.parent = SnapTarget;
            snapped = true;
        }
    }
    public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {

        Debug.Log("exit");
        if (snapped == true && other.transform.GetInstanceID() == SnapTarget.GetInstanceID())
        {
            snapObj.position = transform.position;
            snapObj.rotation = transform.rotation;
            snapObj.parent = transform;
            snapped = false;
            StartCoroutine(noSnap);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    public class collider_helper : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject recieving;
    collider_help_reciever reciever;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        reciever = recieving.GetComponent<collider_help_reciever>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerStay (Collider other)
    {
        reciever.OnTriggerEnter(other);
    }
    public interface collider_help_reciever
    {
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer turned out to be adding a float (lastSnapTime) to store the last time the objects decoupled, and only allowing snapping to happen if some time had passed since they last decoupled:

```
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("enter");
    if (other.transform.GetInstanceID() == SnapTarget.GetInstanceID())
    {
        if (lastSnapTime + 0.1f < Time.time)
        {
            snapObj.position = SnapTarget.position;
            snapObj.rotation = SnapTarget.rotation;
            snapObj.parent = SnapTarget;
        }
    }
}
public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{

    Debug.Log("exit");
    if (other.transform.GetInstanceID() == SnapTarget.GetInstanceID())
    {
        lastSnapTime = Time.time;
        snapObj.position = transform.position;
        snapObj.rotation = transform.rotation;
        snapObj.parent = transform;
        //StartCoroutine(noSnap);
    }
}
```